# Почему зарезается по краям фоновая картинка?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, изображения

Есть [демо сайт](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/28/) в header которого помещено фоновое паралакс изображение, но проблема в том, что оно обрезается по краям из-за неправильного соотношения высоты и ширины (не спасает даже background-size:cover.
Пытаюсь это исправить с помощью скрипта заданием отношения высоты к ширине, но получаю эффект не тот, на который рассчитываю - как быть?

```
( function( $ ) {
  $('header').height($('header').width()/1.5);
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('header').height($('header').width()/1.5);
  });
} )( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На размер фоновой картинки влияет свойство `background-size`, в вашем случае это `background-size: cover;`
`cover` масштабирует изображение так, чтобы вписать его с сохранением пропорций во всю ширину и высоту блока, при этом что-то может обрезаться, если пропорции блока и изображения не совпадают
`contain` впишет изображение целиком, но при несовпадении пропорций картинки и блока вокруг могут появиться незаполненные пустоты

**Обновление**
Если выставлять высоту с помощью jQuery, то код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
(function($) {
    var imgHeight = 600, //высота фонового изображения
        imgWidth = 1500; //ширина фонового изображения
    $('header').height($('header').width()*imgHeight/imgWidth);
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('header').height($('header').width()*imgHeight/imgWidth);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Свойство `background-size` при этом смените на `contain`.

Comment: и как же поступить в моем случае, чтобы вся картинка влезла - уменьшить контейнер с паралаксом?

Comment: ну, например, с помощью js выставляйте высоту блока в зависимости от его ширины так, чтобы соблюдались пропорции изображения

Comment: делаю так `( function( $ ) {

  $('header').height($('header').width()/1.5);

  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('header').height($('header').width()/1.5);

  });

} )( jQuery );`, но эффект получаю не тот, на который рассчитывал

Comment: ну, во-первых, `background-size` неплохо бы всё же сменить на `contain`. И определять размеры блока по правилу пропорции. Как вы делаете это сейчас я не поняла) смотрите обновление в ответе

Comment: спасибо, но почему-то вверху еще фотка обрезается..

Comment: Вы, наверное, имеете в виду то, что прилипающая шапка закрывает часть изображения? Ну тут уж вопрос в размещении блоков :) ну, либо, прибавляйте к высоте блока высоту шапки и свойством `background-position` опускайте фон на прибавленную высоту